# Unrevoke a certificate which was revoked with a status different from Certificate Hold

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, revoked

Is there a way to unrevoke a revoked certificate, which was revoked with the “Superseded” reason code?

I'm using the Certification Authority provided with Windows Server 2008 SP2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once on the revoked list... it stays on the revoked list.  That's why they recommend you NEVER revoke a cert unless you know it's been compromised.

Comment: Well it's not necessarily a matter of compromising a certificate. In my case an employee left the company, his certificate has been revoked with the reason code “Affiliation Change”. Later on, it was discovered  we needed to give him access to a certain system. Hence I wanted to unrevoke the certificate… and it can't be done.

Answer (score 5):

Certificates revoked with the reason code "Certificate Hold" can be unrevoked, left on "Certificate Hold" until they expire, or have their revocation reason code changed. "Certificate Hold" is the only revocation reason that will allow you to unrevoke the certificate. It is useful if the status of the certificate is questionable and is meant to provide some flexibility to the CA administrator.

To unrevoke a certificate revoked with the reason code "Certificate Hold," at a command prompt on the CA, type:

certutil -revoke CertificateSerialNumber unrevoke